# Iterate over nested Struct and return total of values on each struct

Tags: swift, struct

I am experimenting with Swift, trying to create a basic game engine.

I have a `Struct` that defines a fighter, within that are a number of structs used to define the skill set a fighter has.

I would like to iterate over each 'fighter' and total up each individual skill set, returning essentially 3 values - the totals of `standUp, clinch, ground`

I can iterate over the `Fighter` struct, however I am them only able to log out those nested structs.

How should I approach looping over the struct and then looping over the nested structs, return the total of each loop as it's own value? perhaps as part of a tuple?

```
import UIKit

struct StandUp {
    let boxing: Int
    let kickBoxing: Int
}

struct Clinch {
    let judo: Int
    let freestyle: Int
}

struct Ground {
    let bjj: Int
    let judo: Int
}

struct Fighter {
    let standUp: StandUp
    let clinch: Clinch
    let ground: Ground
}

let striker = Fighter(
    standUp: StandUp(boxing: 8, kickBoxing: 7),
    clinch: Clinch(judo: 5, freestyle: 4),
    ground: Ground(bjj: 6, judo: 5)
)

let bjj = Fighter(
    standUp: StandUp(boxing: 5, kickBoxing: 4),
    clinch: Clinch(judo: 7, freestyle: 8),
    ground: Ground(bjj: 8, judo: 7)
)

class FightEngine {
    private let fOne: Fighter
    private let fTwo: Fighter

    init(fighterOne: Fighter, fighterTwo: Fighter) {
        fOne = fighterOne
        fTwo = fighterTwo
    }

   private func sumSkillSet(fighter: Fighter) -> Int {
        var total: Int
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: fighter)

        for skill in mirror.children {
            print(skill.value)
        }

        return 1 // Only returning this so the code will run
    }


    func getTotals() -> (Int, Int) {
        let totalOne = sumSkillSet(fighter: fOne)
        let totalTwo = sumSkillSet(fighter: fTwo)

        return (1, 2) // Only returning this so the code will run
    }

}


let fE = FightEngine(fighterOne: striker, fighterTwo: bjj)

fE.getTotals() // This should be a dictionary of each fighters totals, 3 values for each fighter
```

Ideally I would like some sort of return from `fE.getTotals()` like

```
["fighterOne":(1,2,3), "fighterTwo":(4,5,6)]
```

Comment: Show what output you are expecting. If it is a dictionary, show how that dictionary should look like.

Comment: I have added the type of return object I would like

Comment: What are the three values when your sum method return only a single sum? What are the three values for each fighter then?

Comment: The 3 values (1,2,3) / (4,5,6) are the sum of each fighters `standUp, clinch and ground` structs

Comment: My sum method does not allow me to sum these yet, I'm not sure how to achieve this correctly

Comment: You have not shown the `Mirror` class.

Comment: Mirror is a standard Swift library https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror

Comment: Ah i see. I have posted a solution. However, it doesn't include `Mirror`, but it might still solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
struct StandUp {
    let boxing: Int
    let kickBoxing: Int

    func sum() -> Int {
        return boxing + kickBoxing
    }
}

struct Clinch {
    let judo: Int
    let freestyle: Int

    func sum() -> Int {
        return judo + freestyle
    }
}

struct Ground {
    let bjj: Int
    let judo: Int

    func sum() -> Int {
        return bjj + judo
    }
}

struct Fighter {
    let standUp: StandUp
    let clinch: Clinch
    let ground: Ground

    func sum() -> [Int] {
        return [standUp.sum(), clinch.sum(), ground.sum()]
    }
}

let striker = Fighter(
    standUp: StandUp(boxing: 8, kickBoxing: 7),
    clinch: Clinch(judo: 5, freestyle: 4),
    ground: Ground(bjj: 6, judo: 5)
)

let bjj = Fighter(
    standUp: StandUp(boxing: 5, kickBoxing: 4),
    clinch: Clinch(judo: 7, freestyle: 8),
    ground: Ground(bjj: 8, judo: 7)
)

class FightEngine {
    private let fOne: Fighter
    private let fTwo: Fighter

    init(fighterOne: Fighter, fighterTwo: Fighter) {
        fOne = fighterOne
        fTwo = fighterTwo
    }

    func getTotals() -> [String: [Int]] {
        return ["fighterOne": fOne.sum(), "fighterTwo": fTwo.sum()]
    }

}
```

**Note:** I recommend you add a parameter `name` to `Fighter` and use that as the key instead of "fighterOne" and "fighterTwo".

```
[fOne.name: totalOne, fTwo.name: totalTwo]
```

Comment: This is a better approach than the proposed `Mirror` approach.  For most problems introspection (`Mirror`, etc.) is the wrong solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a much better approach, I can see it scaling better and it provides much more control. Thank you again so much for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an enum, where each case represents a skill set that has init arguments used to calculate the total score of the skill set.

```
enum SkillSet {

    case standUp(boxing: Int, kickBoxing: Int)
    case clinch(judo: Int, freestyle: Int)
    case ground(bjj: Int, judo: Int)

    var score: Int {
        switch self {
        case .standUp(let boxing, let kickBoxing): return boxing + kickBoxing
        case .clinch(let judo, let freestyle): return judo + freestyle
        case .ground(let bjj, let judo): return bjj + judo
        }
     }
}
```

A fighter can have an array of `SkillSet`, with with we can reduce a total score by summing together the score of each skill set.

```
struct Fighter {

    let skillSets: [SkillSet]

    var total: Int {
        return skillSets.reduce(0) { (sum, skillSet) in
            return sum + skillSet.score
        }
    }
}
```

Your engine can be simplified and only be concerned with initiating the fight and giving the score.

```
class FightEngine {

    let fighters: (Fighter, Fighter)

    init(one: Fighter, two: Fighter) { self.fighters = (one, two) }

    func getTotals() -> (Int, Int) { return (fighters.0.total, fighters.1.total) }
}
```

*ding ding*

```
let fightEngine = FightEngine(
    one: Fighter(
        skillSets: [
            .standUp(boxing: 8, kickBoxing: 7),
            .clinch(judo: 5, freestyle: 4),
            .ground(bjj: 6, judo: 5)
        ]
    ),
    two: Fighter(
        skillSets: [
            .standUp(boxing: 5, kickBoxing: 4),
            .clinch(judo: 7, freestyle: 8),
            .ground(bjj: 8, judo: 7)
        ]
    )
)

print(fightEngine.getTotals())
```

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you so much, I like this approach also :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you run into any problems with an enum implementation, check this out – https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples